# How to pass column name in scalar function in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

I am creating a scalar function in sql server.And passing column name as parameter in function.In this function I am using those column name with that table. Here `@FromCurrency` and `@ToCurrency` are column names of `CurrencyConversion` table.
Code as follows:

```
alter FUNCTION fnCurrencyConversion  --1200.90,'NGN','CAD' 
      (@MoneyAmount MONEY,
       @FromCurrency nvarchar(20),
       @ToCurrency nvarchar(20))  
RETURNS decimal(18,2)  
AS  
BEGIN 
  declare @BaseToUsd nvarchar(1000), @UsdToTarget nvarchar(1000)
  declare @Rate decimal(18,5) 
  set @BaseToUsd= ('select top 1 '+ @FromCurrency  +' from CurrencyConversion order by id desc')
  set @UsdToTarget = ('select top 1 '+ @ToCurrency  +'  from CurrencyConversion order by id desc') 

  set @Rate = @UsdToTarget/@BaseToUsd
  declare @TotalAmt decimal(18,5)
  set @TotalAmt = (@Rate * @MoneyAmount)  
  return @TotalAmt 

END
```

How to pass column name in scalar valued function in sql?

Comment: UDF's do not support using dynamic SQL, and even if they did you have the wrong syntax.

Answer (score 1):

UDF's do not support using dynamic SQL, and even if they did you have the wrong syntax.

You could make a stored procedure that does this, along the lines of:

```
create procedure procCurrencyConversion  --1200.90,'NGN','CAD' 
      (@MoneyAmount MONEY,
       @FromCurrency nvarchar(20),
       @ToCurrency nvarchar(20))  
AS  
BEGIN 
  declare @BaseToUsd nvarchar(1000), @UsdToTarget nvarchar(1000)
  declare @Rate decimal(18,5) 
  declare @SQL nvarchar(4000)

  set @SQL = 'select top 1 @BaseToUsd ='+ @FromCurrency  +N' from CurrencyConversion order by id desc'
  exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@BaseToUsd nvarchar(1000) output', @BaseToUsd output

  set @SQL = 'select top 1 @UsdToTarget='+ @ToCurrency  +N' from CurrencyConversion order by id desc'
  exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@UsdToTarget nvarchar(1000) output', @UsdToTarget output

  set @Rate = @UsdToTarget/@BaseToUsd
  declare @TotalAmt decimal(18,5)
  set @TotalAmt = (@Rate * @MoneyAmount)  
  select @TotalAmt 

END
```

Note that [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) has a pretty terse syntax, and is not for the feint of heart :)
Additionally, I would suggest normalizing the `CurrencyConversion` table, so that you can get the data without dynamic SQL, something along the lines of a `Currency` column and inserting one row per currency, not using a separate field for each.
Also, try to avoid UDF's as much as possible, especially on a large dataset, because they work in a row-by-agonizing-row manner, and are huge performance bottlenecks.

Comment: What normalisation rule do you think the current `CurrencyConversion` table breaks? 1NF? It isn't a repeating group along the same lines as `phone1,phone2` IMO as the columns are representing different currencies not multiple instances of the same thing.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, it is a repeating group (of 1 column) and yes they are multiple instance of the "currency-value" thing. It's more of a "verizon-phone","tmobile-phone","att-phone" situation, but it's still the same thing.

Comment: So if a table has columns `startDate` and `endDate` would you also say it has  multiple instance of the "date value" thing? - Not disputing that refactoring so adding a new currency doesn't involve adding columns might not be a bad idea but not sure that [it breaks 1NF](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/facts-and-fallacies-about-first-normal-form/)

Comment: @MartinSmith: No, those are rigidly defined, and a new `midDate` seems unlikely. Also there can be different usages and rules for `startDate` and `endDate` (i.e. `start` is not null and `end` is null). Currencies on the other hand all have the same rules and calculations available to them.

Comment: I'll have to mull that one over!